Where can I read about excitons?
I'm having a tough time finding a good reference for excitons. I know next to nothing about them, and I'd like to find a good book/paper/notes that would introduce it in a slow, pedagogical way. Things like how to compute their energies, wavefunctions, the Bethe-Salpeter equation and I guess a lot more that I don't know but I should've. Do you know some? Thanks in advance!

Pankove's Optical Processes in Semiconductors (Dover) is a classic.

Thank you @JonCuster! I'll check it out

I have recently found the following book to be useful.
Bose-Einstein Condensation of excitons and biexcitons 1, or really any of David Snoke's books
